# Сколько места занимает std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Интересует такой момент сколько места занимает std::vector int на 10x10 элементов в x64?

например просто std::vector на 10 значений занимает 24байта(сам объект) + 10x4байта(10 значений int) = 64байта,

```
vector<int> a (10,1);
```

соответственно 10x10 элементов будет занимать 24 + 24x10 + 10x10x4 = 664байта или 24 + 10x10x4 = 424байта?

```
vector<vector <int>> и (10,vector <int> (10,1));
```

Возник еще один вопрос, если я объявил вектор

```
vector<vector <int>> b (10,vector <int> (10));
```

но заполнил допустим только один его элемент числом, например

```
b[1][1] = 5;
```

остальные элементы второго вектора будут занимать 4 байта, или пока я не присвоил им значение, то место занимает только структура вектора? соответственно размер 24 + 24x10 + 4 = 268, или в любом случае будет 664байта?

Comment: `std::vector` занимает место как в стеке, так и в heap'е. По стандарту гарантировано, что он занимает суммарно `O(n)` памяти, и думаю даже, что n * sizeof(T) + O(1). Но на конкретные константы в O(1) никто, думаю, гарантии не даст.

Comment: Зависит от реализации: в одной версии пустой std::string у меня занимал 0x10 байт, в другой - 0x1C, а в отладочной сборке 0x20. С векторами скорее всего аналогичная ситуация.

Answer (score 5):

N*N `vector<vector<int>>` занимает

```
sizeof(vector) + sizeof(vector)*N + sizeof(int)*N*N + α(N)
```

где α(N) - накладные расходы на выделение памяти в хипе (хипу надо хранить сколько там выделено)

sizeof(vector) - это обычно `3*sizeof(void*)`, и он не зависит от типа который хранится в векторе. (Теоретически возможен вектор меньшего размера, но так никто не делает).

Comment: спасибо, я так и думал, попробую обойтись одномерным вектором, ну или если не получится, то использую эту статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/112826/

Comment: @xttz: Вам жалко несчастных пол-килобайта? Вы создаёте сами себе проблемы.

Comment: @VladD у меня массив результатов четырехмерный(это количество параметров для расчета) и хранится в нем будет в худшем случае 32млн объектов по 14байт каждый. весь размер массива >400мб, так что потратить 350кб на структуру не так и жалко, но только в том случае если пустые элементы (которые точно будут) не будут занимать место

Comment: @xttz: 400 мегабайт — это не так уж много. Особенно если вы компилируете под 64-битную платформу.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в формула должна выглядеть следующим образом: `sizeof(vector) + N*(sizeof(vector) + sizeof(int)*N) + α(N)`, т. е. по факту разница лишь в `sizeof(int)*N*N`, или я где-то ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2):

Размер вектора состоит непосредственно из памяти под структуру и выделенной памяти под массив.

При том способе, каким ты создаёшь вектора, их вместимость будет фиксированной, т. е. равна тому числу элементов, которое ты запрашиваешь. Выделится сразу вся память, естественно.

Исключением является `vector<bool>`, который должен держать значения в битах, а не байтах.

В общем случае, насколько я помню, при использовании только операций добавления, можно рассчитывать, что вместимость вектора превосходит количество элементов в нём не более чем в 2 раза. <s>При добавлении и удалении - в 4 раза.</s> Оказывается, вектор [не уменьшается](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1401015/178988) при удалении ([пример](https://tio.run/##pZDNDoIwDIDve4omHhwxEjx5GPIqppaKizCW/RjU@Ow44OAd20vzpf3alKzdN0TjuNGG2lgzlLr3wTF2lfixB1PoXSVE9No0YLBjb5EYfKiVENoE6FAbmYm3AFi6k8mEClAlQn0MUJaAudcvltlUb1POiDCpdHgumE3dJiXANSnkZB5OhYKhPBRzKNjthiyN2ehv5wvSXQ7Z2h2YO567j38obG@XO/5wsEPPEvMLN9MbV5sch@gMFEp8xvEL)).

---

http://codepad.org/mTvWj83Z

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
  {
  vector < vector <int> > v(10, vector <int> (10,1));
  printf("%d + %d*%d + %d*%d", sizeof v, v.capacity(), sizeof v[0], v[0].capacity(), sizeof v[0][0]);
  printf(" = %d\n", sizeof v + v.capacity() * sizeof v[0] + v[0].capacity() * sizeof v[0][0]);
  return 0;
  }
```

Выводит:

```
28 + 10*28 + 10*4 = 348
```

Answer (score 1):

Размер занимаемой памяти вектором зависит от конкретной реализации класса вектора и размера типа значения, Например размер типа `int` также может меняться в зависимости от среды, где запускается программа.

Если запустить данную тестовую программу

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( 10, std::vector<int>( 10 ) );

    size_t size1, size2, size3;

    std::cout << "sizeof( std::vector<std::vector<int>> ) = " 
              << ( size1 = sizeof( std::vector<std::vector<int>> ) ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "v.capacity() * sizeof( vector<int> ) = " 
              << ( size2 = v.capacity() * sizeof( std::vector<int> ) ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "v[0].capacity() * sizeof( int ) = " 
              << ( size3 = v[0].capacity() * sizeof( int ) ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Total occupied memory size1 + size2 + 10 * size3 = " 
              << size1 + size2 + 10 * size3 << std::endl;
}
```

то онлайновый компилятор MS VC++ выдает следующие значения:

```
sizeof( std::vector<std::vector<int>> ) = 12

v.capacity() * sizeof( vector<int> ) = 120

v[0].capacity() * sizeof( int ) = 40

Total occupied memory size1 + size2 + 10 * size3 = 532
```

В то время как компилятор gcc 5.2.0 выдает следующий результат:

```
sizeof( std::vector<std::vector<int>> ) = 24
v.capacity() * sizeof( vector<int> ) = 240
v[0].capacity() * sizeof( int ) = 40
Total occupied memory size1 + size2 + 10 * size3 = 664
```

Как видите, даже при одинаковом размере типа `int` размер самого объекта типа `std::vector` разный для разных компиляторов.

В VS VC++ этот размер равен 12 байтам, в то время как в gcc 5.2.0 он равен 24 байтам.

Comment: @Abyx  Это не имеет никакого значения. Вопрос о том, как определяется суммарная память, занимаемая вектором. Я предоставил тестовую программу, которая может быть запущена на любой платформе.