# Изменение размера std::vector и его остаточная емкость

Tags: c++, vector, стандарт

Из описания std::vector::resize: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

Никак не могу понять - при изменении размера вектора в меньшую сторону - его capacity гарантировано остается тем, что было до изменения размера или же на усмотрение реализации ?

Comment: В стандарте ничего нет об изменении емкости. Если бы что-то такое происходило - об этом должно было бы быть написано, так как это могло бы приводить к неприятностям. Так что считаю, что емкость будет неизменной.

Comment: @Harry from Kiev, но, если в стандарте нет ничего про изменение емкости, то значит изменение емкости не запрещено. А что не запрещено, то разрешено.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что `resize` инвалидирует итераторы/указатели, и об этом не написано? Хотя в других случаях это явно оговорено. А ваше "что не запрещено, то разрешено" фактически разрешает при `resize` винт отформатировать - не запрещено же!

Comment: @Harry from Kiev, да resize() инвалидирует итераторы на те элементы, которые были ресйзнуты. Я не только хочу это сказать, я говорю это. Об этом написано.

Comment: Он НЕ инвалидирует итераторы на *валидные* элементы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменение размера буфера вектора приводит к инвалидации всех итераторов и ссылок на все его элементы. При этом изменение размера буфера в большую сторону может быть и неявным (например при обычном `emplace_back`), а в меньшую сторону - только явным, при вызове `shrink_to_fit`. Соответственно метод `resize` (и `reserve` тоже) никогда не уменьшает `capacity`.

Comment: Выглядит убедительно, но чисто с формальной точки зрения, что мешает «злой» реализации возвращать уменьшенный `capacity` при этом не изменяя фактический размер буфера? Т.е. и `capacity` уменьшили и итераторы не инвалидировали.

Comment: Мешает то, что `capacity` не должно тут уменьшаться. Ну и `capcity` и размер буфера - это одно и то же. Понятно, что у буфера еще наверное есть какой-то свой размер с точки зрения менеджера памяти,  однако инвалидация происходит именно при модификации логического размера буфера, который доступен как `capacity`, а меняется ли реальный буфер или он остается точно таким же - не важно.

Comment: `инвалидация происходит именно при модификации логического размера буфера` из каких пунктов стандарта это следует?

Comment: @wololo Из описания методов vector. Собственно размер нижележащего буфера там вообще нигде не фигурирует, только `capacity`.

Comment: Как-то расплывчато :) Ну, например, смотрим [`erase`](http://eel.is/c++draft/containers#vector.modifiers-3). Допустим мы удаляем последний элемент вектора. Теперь часть итераторов не валидна, итераторы на элементы перед удаляемым — валидны, один раз вызван деструктор для элемента вектора, подлежащий буфер остался нетронутым. Что мешает вызову `capacity()` возвращать значение на единицу меньше, чем до удаления элемента?

Comment: @wololo То, что изменение `capacity`  отсутствует в перечисленных эффектах.

Answer (score 4):

В стандарте ничего нет об изменении емкости. Если бы что-то такое происходило - об этом было бы написано, так как это могло бы приводить к неприятностям. Например, к перемещению памяти, т.е. к инвалидации итераторов/указателей на остающиеся в контейнере элементы, ко времени работы O(n) и т.д.

В стандарте все такие неприятности оговариваются явно.

Так что емкость будет неизменной.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: но, если в стандарте нет ничего про изменение емкости, то значит изменение емкости не запрещено. А что не запрещено, то разрешено.

Comment: В частности, разрешено отформатировать винт. Не запрещено же? :) Смешно даже. Кстати, у меня хоть какое-то обоснование с учетом написанного в стандарте; остальные ответы скорее рассуждения...

Comment: `к инвалидации итераторов/указателей, ко времени работы O(n)`, Да, `std::vector::resize` инвалидирует итераторы начиная с удалённого элемента и имеет линейную сложность.

Comment: @wololo Естественно, итератор на удаленный элемент валидным не бывает :) Неужели это надо было писать явно?... А вот на неудаленные - нет, эти итераторы не инвалидируются.

Comment: А разве там нет чего-то про реальный размер не более чем в 4 раза больше занятого при удалениях?

Comment: @Qwertiy Что-то не нашел, покажите.

Comment: Хм.. Что-то он вообще жаться не хочет... [tio.run](//tio.run/##pZDNDoIwDIDve4omHhwxEjx5GPIqppaKizCW/RjU@Ow44OAd20vzpf3alKzdN0TjuNGG2lgzlLr3wTF2lfixB1PoXSVE9No0YLBjb5EYfKiVENoE6FAbmYm3AFi6k8mEClAlQn0MUJaAudcvltlUb1POiDCpdHgumE3dJiXANSnkZB5OhYKhPBRzKNjthiyN2ehv5wvSXQ7Z2h2YO567j38obG@XO/5wsEPPEvMLN9MbV5sch@gMFEp8xvEL)

Comment: @Qwertiy Мне казалось, я это доказал :) - ну, что он не должен жаться. `shrink_to_fit`, и то у кого-то (Саттер?) читал, что не гарантируется...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev, а чего мне [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445169/178988) никто об этом не сказал?) Хм.. хотя под [другим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723290/178988) говорили, но не особо настойчиво...

Comment: @Qwertiy Наверное, просто внимания не обратили? :)

Answer (score -1):

Сам контейнерный класс(в частности std::vector), не занимается распределением памяти, это делает отдельный класс _ его `allocator_type`, который передается вторым параметром шаблона. Так, что вы можете передать туда любой распределитель, и он останется стандартным вектором.

Если речь идет о стандартном распределителе, который передается по умолчанию, то он не может себе позволить выполнять не эффективные действия, в том числе и перераспределение памяти( в случаи, если контейнеру нужна память меньше, чем для него уже было распределено. Ответ однозначен _ стандартный распределитель   гарантировано оставляет выделенную память тем, что было до изменения размера, если даже есть попытка изменить размера вектора в меньшую сторону (то есть **стандартный**`allocator_type::deallocate`
ничего не делает в этом случаи).

Comment: Все-таки это решает сам вектор, а не его аллокатор.

Comment: Вопрос - как написать свой аллокатор так, чтобы емкость уменьшалась? Если `resize` по сути к нему не обращается?

Comment: "allocator_type::deallocate в любой своей реализации должна ... выделить новый кусок подходящей памяти" Закусывать надо.

Comment: @Harry from Kiev, если функция_член не обращается к распределителю,  при попытке изменить размер, значит тем более емкость не меняется, но я обобщал _ если даже есть  обращение, то стандартный распределитель этого не сделает.

Comment: Я просто к тому, что, как мне кажется, что аллокатор к данному вопросу в полной мере ни при чем...

Comment: @Harry from Kiev,  да, я  не очень удачно пытался доказывать, что в любом случаи deallocate ничего не сделает